# Why docker-compose build start from begining

Tags: docker, docker-compose

For example.

Every time I build.

- Copy package.json
- Install package.json
- Add current directory.

My question is:

Why it does not use from the cache. For example, It should not install the package.json from the start if the package.json does not change.

It should use the cache and update only the changes code.

**Update**:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y  --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    ca-certificates \
    gcc \
    git \
    libpq-dev \
    make \
    python-pip \
    python2.7 \
    python2.7-dev \
    apt-transport-https \
    curl \
    g++ \
    sudo \
    wget \
    bzip2 \
    chrpath \
    libssl-dev \
    libxft-dev \
    libfreetype6 \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libfontconfig1-dev \
    libfontconfig \
    poppler-utils \
    imagemagick \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get -y autoclean

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  --no-install-recommends software-properties-common && add-apt-repository ppa:malteworld/ppa && apt update && apt install -y  --no-install-recommends pdftk \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get -y autoclean


ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 10.6.0

# Install nvm with node and npm
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.29.0/install.sh | bash \
    && source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

# Set up our PATH correctly so we don't have to long-reference npm, node, &c.
ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

# Set the work directory
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/app/jobsaf-website
RUN mkdir /data
RUN mkdir /data/db

WORKDIR /var/www/app/jobsaf-website

RUN npm install -g node-gyp @angular/cli@6.2.3 nodemon  request


# Add our package.json and install *before* adding our application files
COPY package.json ./

# RUN npm install --force
RUN npm install --force

RUN npm rebuild node-sass


# Add application files
ADD . .

EXPOSE 3000 5858 4200 35729 27017 6379 49153
```

`.dockerignore`

```
# See http://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# compiled output
/tmp
/public/__build__/
/src/*/__build__/
/__build__/**
/public/dist/
/src/*/dist/
/dist/**
/.awcache
.webpack.json
/compiled/
dll/

package-lock.json
# dependencies
/node_modules
*/node_modules
# IDEs and editors
/.idea
.project
.classpath
.c9/
*.launch
**.js.map
.settings/

# IDE - VSCode
.vscode/


# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage/*
/libpeerconnection.log
npm-debug.log
testem.log
/typings

# e2e
/e2e/*.js
/e2e/*.map

#System Files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db

*.csv
*.dat
*.iml
*.log
*.out
*.pid
*.seed
*.sublime-*
*.swo
*.swp
*.tgz
*.xml
.strong-pm
coverage

npm-debug*
/admin/dist

npm
/.cache-loader/*
stats.json

!/src/assets/js/admin-header.js
!/src/assets/js/website-custom.js

webpack-cache/
web/

/src/app/**/*.map
/src/app/**/*.js
```

Comment: Can you show us your code and how you are doing the build and what is the output of that build ?

Comment: It sounds correct, maybe there is some other instruction before that causes a cache invalidation , and you have to know that when a layer is rebuilt, all other following  do the same. Can you show your Dockerfile and.Dockerignore?

Comment: I have added Dockerfile and .dockerignore

Comment: @MostafaHussein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--force` should be removed from the following line as it will ignore any cache and do a fresh installation for your packages which leads to a new docker build layer starting from the installation step.

```
RUN npm install --force
```

> The -f or --force argument will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk.

Comment: I will check and  back to you